# Переход с вкладки

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой такой как при переходе с вкладки сайта и в последующем при возвращений на неё скрипт ведёт себя не адекватно. Смысл скрипта в том чтобы для начала довести до opacity 0, заменить картинку и вернуть opacity до 1. При нахождений на вкладке всё хорошо, но при потере фокуса и через время если вернутся картинка начинает мигать. Помогите пофиксить этот недуг

```js
function animation() {
    let mainWindow = document.querySelector('.main');
    setInterval(function() {
        let item = 1.0;
        let checker = 0;
        if (checker === 0) {
        let stopInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (item > 0.01 && checker === 0) {
                item -= 0.01;
                mainWindow.style.opacity = item;
                console.log(item)
            } else if (item <= 0.01 && checker === 0) {
                let score = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 17);
                mainWindow.style.backgroundImage = `url(img/animation/${score}.jpg)`;
                checker = 1;       
            } else if (item <= 1.0 && checker === 1) {
                item += 0.01;
                mainWindow.style.opacity = item;
                console.log(item)
            } else if (item >= 1.0 && checker === 1) {
                checker = 0;
                clearInterval(stopInterval)
            }
        }, 50)
        }
    }, 30000)
```

Comment: Когда таб становится неактивным - все таймеры приостановливаются и откладывают свою работу до активации таба. Когда таб снова акивируется, остановленный таймер продолжает свою работу, но так как прошел интервал, вместе с ним запускается и новый таймер. И теперь работают оба таймера одновременно и происходит лаг анимации. Для того, чтобы сделать нормальные анимации вы должны привязываься не к интервалам таймеров, а к реальному времени анимации. Решения подобных задач нужно строить на базе функций requestAnimationFrame, и  cancelAnimationFramе и учитывать, что таб может "заснуть" в любое время.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена